# Does Chrome have issue with setting a:visited css properties?

Tags: css, google-chrome, hyperlink, background-color

I am unable to set the background color for a `:visited` hyperlink to a different background-color.

Is this a known issue for Google Chrome? I have seen people raising similar issue with background-image. Setting the color attribute seems to be working fine.

This is the code that I used:

```
a:visited{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Not a duplicate because the resolution of that one is that background-image isn't supposed to work (for security reasons) but background-color *is*.

Comment: e.g. http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead, use the following:

```
a {
   background-color: white;
}

a:visited{
    background-color: red;
}
```

For security reasons -- specifically, in order to prevent history sniffing -- Chrome limits very strictly what can be done using the :visited selector.

Comment: @praveen That's probably because there's no difference between OP's code and the code in this answer; the a:visited property and value is exactly the same.