# Issue with background color of a button after visited state

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Issue with background color of a button after visited state

https://jsfiddle.net/vivekraj_kr/wxokhpy4/

how to get a background color on button visited

```
<button type="button" class="size_btn">S</button>
<button type="button" class="size_btn">M</button>
<button type="button" class="size_btn">L</button>
<button type="button" class="size_btn">XL</button>



.size_btn {
height:27px;
width: 27px;
background: none;
border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.size_btn:visited {
background-color: #479c3d;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try working with `<a>` because `<button>` has nothing to do with `:visited`

```css
a.button {
    height:27px;
    width: 27px;
    background: none;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    font: 80% Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: none;
    background-color: white;
}

a.button:visited {
     background-color: red;   
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">S</a>
<a href="#" class="button">M</a>
<a href="#" class="button">L</a>
<a href="#" class="button">XL</a>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y5Lcrboo/)

*Note: Google Chrome has an issue setting `a:visited` property. Check out more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727993/does-google-chrome-has-issue-with-setting-avisited-css-properties) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788855/google-chrome-avisited-background-image-not-working).*

Hope that helps.

Comment: @VIVEKRAJ You can also add a class to the selected button, and style it like you want. However I would use JavaScript/jQuery for that.

Answer (score 1):

In css **:visited** selector used only for links elements. So instead of **:visited** you either use **:active** selector instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-
    S
    M
    L
    XL

```
<style>



.size_btn {
    height:27px;
    width: 27px;
    background: none;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
/* unvisited link */
.size_btn:link {
    background-color: green;
}

/* visited link */
.size_btn:visited {
    background-color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
.size_btn:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

/* selected link */
.size_btn:active {
    background-color: yellow;
} 
</style>
```