# Why doesn't my a:visited style work in Chrome or IE?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am using a simple HTML selector to change the visited link color. This works in Edge and Firefox, but not in Chrome and IE. Any tips would be great.

```css
a:visited {
  color: pink !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">W3Sschools</a>
<a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a>

<p><b>Note:</b> The :link selector style links to pages you have not visited yet.</p>
```

Comment: Works in Chrome for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does google chrome has issue with setting a:visited css properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727993/does-google-chrome-has-issue-with-setting-avisited-css-properties)

Comment: Not a duplicate (apparently) since this **does** work in Chrome. Should be closed as "unable to reproduce" (based on supplied example).

Comment: have you also set color for `a` ?

Comment: For me it has the same behavior in chrome as described. It works when `open in new tab`

Comment: It works for me in Chrome as well.

Answer (score 1):

When styling a pseudo-class like `:visited` for the `<a>` element, it's a good idea to style *all of them* explicitly, so that you don't get any stylesheet conflicts:

- `a:link`
- `a:visited`
- `a:hover`
- `a:active`

You can remember the correct order with the mnemonic: **L**o**V**e **HA**te

Comment: Works for most links but, except for links opening in a new tab, which have target=_blank in IE 11 & Chrome